# Как решить такую задачу на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно решить такую задачу на python? Причем не усложняя код, максимально просто и лаконично?

Автомат обрабатывает натуральное число N<256 по
следующему алгоритму:

1. Строится восьмибитная двоичная запись числа N.
2. Инвертируются все разряды исходного числа (0
   заменяется на 1, 1 на 0).
3. К полученному двоичному числу прибавляют
   единицу.
4. Полученное число переводится в десятичную
   систему счисления.
   Чему равен результат работы алгоритма для N =
   80?1

Comment: Это задача для решения головным мозгом, не языком программирования.

Comment: Типа `N = -N;` ?

Comment: Примеры бы не помешали

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения.

Comment: @tym32167, подсказывайте более умело. Там беззнаковая арифметика.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy там - это в питоне? Хотел бы я уметь подсказывать более умело 

Comment: @tym32167, в постановке задачи не могут возникнуть отрицательные числа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не оч понял, ну и бог с ним =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = input("Введите число в в диапазоне от 0 до 255: ")
# Проверяем, что введенное значение может быть преобразовано в число
if num.isdigit():
    # Преобразуем строку в число
    num = int(num)
    if num >= 0 and num < 256:
        binary_string = bin(num)[2:].zfill(8) #в 8-битную двоичную запись и отсекаем префиксом '0b'
        inverted_string = format(~int(binary_string, 2) & 0xFF, '08b')# меняем 0 на 1 , а 1 на 0
        new_string = bin(int(inverted_string, 2) + 1)[2:]# прибовляем 1
        result1 = int(new_string, 2) # переводим в десятичную систему

        result2 = 256-num
        print(result1)
        print(result2)
    else:
        print("Ошибка: число должно быть в диапазоне от 0 до 255")
else:
    print("Ошибка: введено некорректное значение")
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, исправил , а теперь ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy result = 256-num?

Comment: N = 80
result = (~N & 0xff) + 1
print(result)

Comment: Верно. Это дополнение до двух.

Comment: Задача явно учебная. И вероятней всего подразумевает что учащийся должен показать навыки работы с массивами, а так же навыки понимания как работает двоичная арифметика. Т.е. реализовать добавление единицы не просто как N + 1. А имея массив из 8 элементов в котором хранятся 0 и 1.